# Java Android xPath html parsing

Tags: java, android, html, xpath, html-table

I'm having an application that need to take html and get some tags inside it.

I need to get all the tr's and all the td's, and get their inner text.

Can you give me a code to do it?

I'm working on this hours already...

The website content is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">    
<!-- Updated: 03/11/2011 15:17:29-->    
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >    
<head><title>    
    Untitled Page    
</title><meta http-equiv="Page-Exit" content="progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.GradientWipe(duration=1)" /><meta HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" /><meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" /><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />    
    <style type="text/css">                
    .DisplayTable { width: 97%; }    
    .DisplayHeader { font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px; color: Black; text-align: center; }    
    .DisplayCell { font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: Black; }                
    .MessageTable { width: 97%; }    
    .MessageHeader { font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; color: SteelBlue; border-bottom: solid 3px SteelBlue; }    
    .MessageText { font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; color: SteelBlue; text-align: right; }                
    .DisplayFillChange { font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: MediumBlue; background-color: LightCyan; border-bottom: solid 1px LightCyan; }    
    .DisplayFreeChange { font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: OrangeRed; background-color: LightCyan; border-bottom: solid 1px LightCyan; }    
    .DisplayEventChange { font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: DarkGreen; background-color: LightCyan; border-bottom: solid 1px LightCyan; }    
    .DisplayExamChange { font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: IndianRed; background-color: LightCyan; border-bottom: solid 1px LightCyan; }                
    </style>    
</head>    
<body dir="rtl" style="margin: 0px; background-color: LightCyan; overflow: hidden;" scroll="no" onload="resize()">    
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="MainScreen.aspx?pid=17&amp;mid=6264&amp;page=5&amp;msgof=0&amp;static=1" id="form1">    
<div>    
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJLTQwMjA0MzQzZGSqqj0xDnBRKxIgowwhNZzzyzQHVg==" />    
</div>            
        <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background-image: url(fill.gif);">    
            <tr height="59" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 34px; color: Yellow; vertical-align: middle;">    
                <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>    
                <td width="45%" align="right" id="clock">00:00</td>    
                <td align="center" nowrap><b>שינוי מערכת שעות לתאריך                        </b></td>    
                <td width="45%" align="left">04.11.2011</td>    
                <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>    
            </tr>    
        </table>    
        <br />    
        <div id="header" align="center"><table width='100%' class='DisplayTable' cellspacing='0' border='1'><tr class='DisplayHeader'><td width='1%' style='color: LightCyan;'>0</td><td width='14%'>יא - 1</td><td width='14%'>יא - 2</td><td width='14%'>יא - 3</td><td width='14%'>יא - 4</td><td width='14%'>יא - 5</td><td width='14%'>יא - 6</td><td width='14%'>יא - 7</td><td width='1%' style='color: LightCyan;'>0</td></tr></table></div>    
        <div id="scrollPanel" align="center" style="overflow: hidden;">    
            <div id="panel" align="center" style=""><table width='100%' class='DisplayTable' cellspacing='0' border='1'><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>0</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>0</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>1</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'><table width='100%'></table></td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>1</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>2</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'><table width='100%'></table></td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>2</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>3</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>3</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>4</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>4</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>5</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>5</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>6</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>6</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>7</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>7</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>8</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>8</td></tr><tr><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>9</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'>&nbsp;</td><td width='1%' class='DisplayCell'>9</td></tr></table></div>    
            <div id="messages" align="center"><table width='100%' class='MessageTable' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='7' border='0'><tr><td class='MessageHeader'>הודעות</td></tr></tr></table></div>    
        </div>    
    </form>    
    <script>                
    var sp;    
    var delay = 0;                
    function resize(){    
        sp = document.getElementById('scrollPanel');    
        sp.style.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - sp.offsetTop;            
        delay = document.getElementById('panel').clientHeight - document.getElementById('scrollPanel').clientHeight;    
        if (delay > 0)    
            delay = delay / 5 * 120;    
        else    
            delay = 0;                    
        setTimeout("doScroll()", 3000);    
        setTimeout("doNextPage()", 500);    
    }                
    function doScroll()    
    {    
        sp.scrollTop += 5;    
        setTimeout("doScroll()", 100);    
    }                
    updateClock();    
    function nextUrl()    
    {    
        return 'MainScreen.aspx?pid=17&mid=6264&page=6&msgof=0&nd=0';    
    }                
    function doNextPage()    
    {                    
    }                
    function updateClock()    
    {    
        document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = getClock();    
        setTimeout("updateClock()", 55000)    
    }
    function getClock()    
    {    
        var date = new Date();    
        var hours = date.getHours();    
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();                    
        if (hours < 10)    
            hours = '0' + hours;                        
        if (minutes < 10)    
            minutes = '0' + minutes;            
        return hours + ':' + minutes;    
    }    
    </script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way out would be using an HTML parsing library, e.g. HTMLCleaner, TagSoup, HTML Parser etc. That way you'll be able to simply fetch al desired elements from the document, or iterate it manually with a 'node visitor' - or whatever the libraries call it.

A quick look at the [documentation](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) of a randomly chosen library from above, suggests something like the following should work for HTMLCleaner:

```
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
TagNode root= cleaner.clean(...);
TagNode[] trNodes= root.getElementsByName("tr");
for (TagNode trNode : trNodes) {
    System.out.println("All text inside this <tr> tag (including children): " + trNode.getText());
}
```

An example using the same library, but now with a TagNodeVisitor and filtered on `<td>`:

```
node.traverse(new TagNodeVisitor() {
    public boolean visit(TagNode tagNode, HtmlNode htmlNode) {
        if (htmlNode instanceof TagNode) {
            TagNode tag = (TagNode) htmlNode;
            String tagName = tag.getName();
            if ("td".equals(tagName)) {
                System.out.println("All text inside this <td> tag (including children): " + tag.getText());
            }
        }
        // tells visitor to continue traversing the DOM tree
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, its great but the problem is that I need only one column in the table. I mean that i need to go in each tr for example to the 2nd td. My friend told me that xPath is great for it because I can choose a td with index. Therefore I have asked for an xPath solution. So I would be glad if you gave me the xPath code, or if you tell me that indexes are also possible with your method. Thank you!!!

Comment: I suppose you could simply call `getChildTags()` inside the loop to get the 2nd `<td>` inside a `<tr>`:

    `for (TagNode trNode : trNodes) {
    TagNode tdNode = trNode.getChildTags[1];
    }`

Alternatively, an xPath evaluation also seems to be (partially) supported using `evaluateXPath(String)`. See [`TagNode`](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/TagNode.html) documentation.

Do note that this assumes the 2nd child will be a `<td>` - you probably want to explicitly check for that.

//edit: sorry, can't seem to get the formatting right.

Comment: Well, Iv'e looked into it, and now I have another problem... I DID manage to get all td's with indexes, but the specific td's I need to find are actually containing a TABLE (very stupid but my app uses an already built website). when there is this situation: `<td width='14%' class='DisplayCell'><table width='100%'><tr><td class='DisplayFillChange'>Some Text Here...</td></tr></table></td>` I didn't manage to create a code to get the text, but while in debug mode I tried to get into those tags, but eventually I couldn't get the text, like it is not exist...